# Ubuntu sound/network/USB trouble after suspend , how to restart

Tags: audio, networking, usb, ubuntu-14.04, suspend

I had a lengthy problem with Ubuntu 14.04 with Lenovo S20-30: after resuming suspended session some things break:

- USB stops recognizing devices

  - due to this the webcam and bluetooth stop working
- NetworkManager goes to sleep and no internet connections are made
- Sound stops or hangs up in false "Headphones" mode,

  - or "Dummy" output is shown in Settings->Sound

Answer (score 1):

This is a summary of many different answers (from the stack and others) on this topic which worked consistently for me:

- to restart USB run in terminal as root e.g. in a scipt:

```
#!/bin/bash
for I in $(ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/|grep : ) ; do 
echo $I
sudo echo $I > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind  
sudo echo $I > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind 
done
```

- to wake up (resume) NetworkManager as normal user

```
#!/bin/bash
nmcli nm sleep false
```

- to restart the sound as root

```
#!/bin/bash
pulseaudio -k ; sudo modprobe -fr snd_hda_intel; sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

this solves the common message which came up upon restart:
`modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel is in use.`

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer by IljaBek into an automate one. Place the following script in a new file called:

`/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_usb_unbind_bind`

```
#!/bin/sh

# Action script to ubind then bind USB devices after sleep
#


case "${1}" in
        hibernate)
                # nothing
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
               for I in $(ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/|grep : ) ; do
                 echo $I > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
                 echo $I > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind 
               done
                ;;
esac
```

Make the file executable with `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_usb_unbind_bind`